# Rails ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying create `notification` to add `user friend`.
However, when I try to add a friend to the error.

**Friendships model**

```
class Friendship < ApplicationRecord
  after_save :notification

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
  has_many :notification

  private
  def all_friendships
    @all_friend = Friendship.order('created_at DESC').limit(1)
  end

  def notification
    all_friendships.each do |friend|
      Notification.create(recipient: friend.friend_id, actor: self.user, action: "add friend", notifiable: friend)
    end
  end
end
```

**Friendships controller**

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_friendships, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index; end  

  def create
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(friend_id: params[:friend_id],
                                                 accepted: false)
    if @friendship.save
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      redirect_to users_path
    end
  end

  def update
    @friendship.update_attributes(accepted: true)
    if @friendship.save
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      redirect_to users_path
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @friendship.destroy
    redirect_to current_user
  end

  private
    def set_friendships
        @friendship = Friendship.where(user_id: params[:id]).or(Friendship.where(friend_id: params[:id])).first
    end
end
```

**Notification model**

```
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :actor, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true

  scope :unread, -> { where(read_at: nil) }
end
```

**Error**

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in FriendshipsController#create
User(#70140147575580) expected, got 2 which is an instance of Integer(#70140150807860)
Extracted source (around line #15):

  def notification
    all_friendships.each do |friend|
      Notification.create(recipient: friend.friend_id, actor: self.user, action: "add friend", notifiable: friend)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You set `friend_id`(Integer) instead of a user model (recipient: friend.frien_id). Need to set user model. Try:

```
def notification
    all_friendships.each do |friend|
      Notification.create(recipient: friend, actor: self.user, action: "add friend", notifiable: friend)
    end
  end
```

UPDATE: It is not good to call variable of `Friendship` class `friend`, as `friend` should be `User`.
Anyway here is the code:

```
def notification
    all_friendships.each do |friend|
      Notification.create(recipient: friend.friend, actor: self.user, action: "add friend", notifiable: friend)
    end
end
```

Comment: anyway an error
User(#70140200960220) expected, got #<Friendship id: 15, user_id: 1, friend_id: 2, accepted: false, created_at: "2018-06-10 14:22:05", updated_at: "2018-06-10 14:22:05"> which is an instance of Friendship(#70140183755940)

Comment: Updated the response